# Reasons for failure of project syncing with gradle in Android Studio3.0.1

Tags: android, gradle

[Screenshot shows no preview of layout and syncing problem with gradle even after adding URI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNTfn.png)

My problems are:
1--Reasons for sync project with gradle failed.
2--Even after adding URI manually, why it shows that URI is not registered.
 I have done some research which provides me the following solutions:

> File->Settings->Build,Execution,Deployment->Gradle .

Click on "Use Local Gradle Distribution" and then in the gradle home add the path of repository.
But these solutions doesn't helped me out.
Finally, I want to ask how to solve my above mentioned problems and what are the reasons behind them and
which repositories do I need to download to remove the sync project failed??

Comment: check File ->ProjectStructure -> project in this path check ***gradle version*** and ***plugin version***

Comment: Path given is as follows  :  Gradle version is==4.4.And Android Plugin Version is== 3.1.2. Now ??

Comment: if you're using 3.3 for this project you'd be deleting the folder

***C:\Users\[user here]\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-3.3-all***